# Incorrect returned cipher text with DES Implementation in Java

Tags: java, des

For a small assignment I have been given to implement the DES algorithm without using predefined functions already in Java. I got it working, however the ciphered text returned is not correct. It returns 6C 17 96 35 BE 47 EF 95 when it should be AA 39 B9 77 7E FC 3C 14.  Any ideas where I went wrong?

*Follow-up; March 8*

Following David Koontz's suggestion using [this manual](https://ia601704.us.archive.org/35/items/validatingcorrec00gait/validatingcorrec00gait.pdf/) he linked me to. I believe that the encryption starts going awry around the subkey generation.

*Follow-up; later March 8*

Having been annoyed and reviewing each step of my code, I found out the problem.  In one of my for loops I used int j=0; i<16; i++  instead of using j's.  Stupid mistake but no one found it either so oh well.  Corrected in the posted code.

```
package des.implementation;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
public class DESImplementation {    
    private static final byte[] IP = { 
        58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2,
        60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 12, 4,
        62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6,
        64, 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8,
        57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9,  1,
        59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 19, 11, 3,
        61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5,
        63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7
    };
    private static final byte[] FP = {
        40, 8, 48, 16, 56, 24, 64, 32,
        39, 7, 47, 15, 55, 23, 63, 31,
        38, 6, 46, 14, 54, 22, 62, 30,
        37, 5, 45, 13, 53, 21, 61, 29,
        36, 4, 44, 12, 52, 20, 60, 28,
        35, 3, 43, 11, 51, 19, 59, 27,
        34, 2, 42, 10, 50, 18, 58, 26,
        33, 1, 41, 9, 49, 17, 57, 25
    };
    private static final byte[] E = {
        32, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
        4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
        8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13,
        12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
        24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
        28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 1
    };
    private static final byte[][] S = { {
        14, 4,  13, 1,  2,  15, 11, 8,  3,  10, 6,  12, 5,  9,  0,  7,
        0,  15, 7,  4,  14, 2,  13, 1,  10, 6,  12, 11, 9,  5,  3,  8,
        4,  1,  14, 8,  13, 6,  2,  11, 15, 12, 9,  7,  3,  10, 5,  0,
        15, 12, 8,  2,  4,  9,  1,  7,  5,  11, 3,  14, 10, 0,  6,  13
    }, {
        15, 1,  8,  14, 6,  11, 3,  4,  9,  7,  2,  13, 12, 0,  5,  10,
        3,  13, 4,  7,  15, 2,  8,  14, 12, 0,  1,  10, 6,  9,  11, 5,
        0,  14, 7,  11, 10, 4,  13, 1,  5,  8,  12, 6,  9,  3,  2,  15,
        13, 8,  10, 1,  3,  15, 4,  2,  11, 6,  7,  12, 0,  5,  14, 9
    }, {
        10, 0,  9,  14, 6,  3,  15, 5,  1,  13, 12, 7,  11, 4,  2,  8,
        13, 7,  0,  9,  3,  4,  6,  10, 2,  8,  5,  14, 12, 11, 15, 1,
        13, 6,  4,  9,  8,  15, 3,  0,  11, 1,  2,  12, 5,  10, 14, 7,
        1,  10, 13, 0,  6,  9,  8,  7,  4,  15, 14, 3,  11, 5,  2,  12
    }, {
        7,  13, 14, 3,  0,  6,  9,  10, 1,  2,  8,  5,  11, 12, 4,  15,
        13, 8,  11, 5,  6,  15, 0,  3,  4,  7,  2,  12, 1,  10, 14, 9,
        10, 6,  9,  0,  12, 11, 7,  13, 15, 1,  3,  14, 5,  2,  8,  4,
        3,  15, 0,  6,  10, 1,  13, 8,  9,  4,  5,  11, 12, 7,  2,  14
    }, {
        2,  12, 4,  1,  7,  10, 11, 6,  8,  5,  3,  15, 13, 0,  14, 9,
        14, 11, 2,  12, 4,  7,  13, 1,  5,  0,  15, 10, 3,  9,  8,  6,
        4,  2,  1,  11, 10, 13, 7,  8,  15, 9,  12, 5,  6,  3,  0,  14,
        11, 8,  12, 7,  1,  14, 2,  13, 6,  15, 0,  9,  10, 4,  5,  3
    }, {
        12, 1,  10, 15, 9,  2,  6,  8,  0,  13, 3,  4,  14, 7,  5,  11,
        10, 15, 4,  2,  7,  12, 9,  5,  6,  1,  13, 14, 0,  11, 3,  8,
        9,  14, 15, 5,  2,  8,  12, 3,  7,  0,  4,  10, 1,  13, 11, 6,
        4,  3,  2,  12, 9,  5,  15, 10, 11, 14, 1,  7,  6,  0,  8,  13
    }, {
        4,  11, 2,  14, 15, 0,  8,  13, 3,  12, 9,  7,  5,  10, 6,  1,
        13, 0,  11, 7,  4,  9,  1,  10, 14, 3,  5,  12, 2,  15, 8,  6,
        1,  4,  11, 13, 12, 3,  7,  14, 10, 15, 6,  8,  0,  5,  9,  2,
        6,  11, 13, 8,  1,  4,  10, 7,  9,  5,  0,  15, 14, 2,  3,  12
    }, {
        13, 2,  8,  4,  6,  15, 11, 1,  10, 9,  3,  14, 5,  0,  12, 7,
        1,  15, 13, 8,  10, 3,  7,  4,  12, 5,  6,  11, 0,  14, 9,  2,
        7,  11, 4,  1,  9,  12, 14, 2,  0,  6,  10, 13, 15, 3,  5,  8,
        2,  1,  14, 7,  4,  10, 8,  13, 15, 12, 9,  0,  3,  5,  6,  11
    } };
    private static final byte[] P = {
        16, 7,  20, 21,
        29, 12, 28, 17,
        1,  15, 23, 26,
        5,  18, 31, 10,
        2,  8,  24, 14,
        32, 27, 3,  9,
        19, 13, 30, 6,
        22, 11, 4,  25
    };
    private static final byte[] PC1 = {
        57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9,
        1,  58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18,
        10, 2,  59, 51, 43, 35, 27,
        19, 11, 3,  60, 52, 44, 36,
        63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15,
        7,  62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22,
        14, 6,  61, 53, 45, 37, 29,
        21, 13, 5,  28, 20, 12, 4
    };
    private static final byte[] PC2 = {
        14, 17, 11, 24, 1,  5,
        3,  28, 15, 6,  21, 10,
        23, 19, 12, 4,  26, 8,
        16, 7,  27, 20, 13, 2,
        41, 52, 31, 37, 47, 55,
        30, 40, 51, 45, 33, 48,
        44, 49, 39, 56, 34, 53,
        46, 42, 50, 36, 29, 32
    };
    private static final byte[] rotations = {
        1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1
    };
    private static int charToNibble(char c) {
        if (c>='0' && c<='9') {
            return (c-'0');
        } else if (c>='a' && c<='f') {
            return (10+c-'a');
        } else if (c>='A' && c<='F') {
            return (10+c-'A');
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    private static byte[] parseBytes(String s) {
        s = s.replace(" ", "");
        byte[] ba = new byte[s.length()/2];
        if (s.length()%2 > 0) { s = s+'0'; }
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i+=2) {
            ba[i/2] = (byte) (charToNibble(s.charAt(i))<<4 | charToNibble(s.charAt(i+1)));
        }
        return ba;
    }
    private static long permute(byte[] table, int srcWidth, long src) {
        long dst = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
            int srcPos = srcWidth - table[i];
            dst = (dst<<1) | (src>>>srcPos & 0x01);
        }
        return dst;
    }
    private static byte[] longToBytes(long x) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
        buffer.putLong(x);
        return buffer.array();
    }   
    private static byte S(int boxNumber, byte src) {
        src = (byte) (src&0x20 | ((src&0x01)<<4) | ((src&0x1E)>>>1));
        return S[boxNumber-1][src];
    }
    private static int  P(int src)    { return (int)permute(P, 32, src&0xFFFFFFFFL); }
    private static int feistel(int r, long subkey) {
        long e = permute(E, 32, r&0xFFFFFFFFL);
        long x = e ^ subkey;
        int dst = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            dst>>>=4;
            int s = S(8-i, (byte)(x&0x3F));
            dst |= s << 28;
            x>>>=6;
        }
        return P(dst);
    }
    private static long bytesToLong(byte[] bytes) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
        buffer.put(bytes);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer.getLong();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] message = parseBytes("0123456789ABCDEF");
        byte[] key = parseBytes("3b3898371520f75e");
            byte[] ciphertext = new byte[message.length];
            for(int i=0; i<message.length; i+=8){
                long Lmessage = bytesToLong(message);
                long Lkey = bytesToLong(key);
                        long subkeys[] = new long[16];
                        Lkey = permute(PC1, 64, Lkey);
                        int c = (int) (Lkey>>>28);
                        int d = (int) (Lkey&0x0FFFFFFF);
                        for (int j=0; j<16; j++) {    //the problem was found here
                            if (rotations[j] == 1) {
                                c = ((c<<1) & 0x0FFFFFFF) | (c>>>27);
                                d = ((d<<1) & 0x0FFFFFFF) | (d>>>27);
                            } else {
                                c = ((c<<2) & 0x0FFFFFFF) | (c>>>26);
                                d = ((d<<2) & 0x0FFFFFFF) | (d>>>26);
                            }
                            long cd = (c&0xFFFFFFFFL)<<28 | (d&0xFFFFFFFFL);
                            subkeys[j] = permute(PC2, 56, cd);
                        }                     
                    long ip = permute(IP, 64, Lmessage);
                    int l = (int) (ip>>>32);
                    int r = (int) (ip&0xFFFFFFFFL);                       
                    for (int k=0; k<16; k++) {
                        int previous_l = l;
                        l = r;
                        r = previous_l^feistel(r, subkeys[k]);
                    }
                    long rl = (r&0xFFFFFFFFL)<<32 | (l&0xFFFFFFFFL);
                    long fp =  permute(FP, 64, rl);
                    ciphertext = longToBytes(fp);
            }
        StringBuilder Message = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder Key = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder Cipher = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<ciphertext.length; i++) {
            Message.append(String.format("%02X ",message[i]));
            Key.append(String.format("%02X ",key[i]));
            Cipher.append(String.format("%02X ",ciphertext[i]));
        }
        System.out.println("Message: "+Message.toString());
        System.out.println("Key: "+Key.toString());
        System.out.println("Cipher: "+Cipher.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Your right shifts should be logical, not arithmetic: `>>>`.

Comment: @EJP i'm not entirely sure where you mean this, but I don't find that fixing anything.  The only thing changed is the dst>>>=4; in the feistel function into dst>>=4; makes the answer 00 D3 AE 13 C6 7D CE DD, which still isn't correct

Comment: If you don't use SRL in the rotations you'll get wrong answers. I haven't asserted that this is the only problem.

Comment: My posts here are comments, not answers. If I had an answer I'd post an answer. If you don't understand why the difference between SRL and SRA is relevant I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: @EJP Understood, I get the idea of SRL vs SRA, this [link][1] was helpful in understanding, would you mind checking if I missed changing any or if I changed one I shouldn't have?     [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269399/srashift-right-arithmetic-vs-srl-shift-right-logical

Comment: @DavidKoontz found and corrected the problem, thanks for your help

Comment: If you solved it, you should answer the question yourself so people in the future with the same problem will know what to do.

Comment: Lawrie Brown's [DES Calculator applet](http://seit.unsw.adfa.edu.au/staff/sites/lpb/src/DEScalc/). Your implementation is more succinct, this one is likely quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having been annoyed and reviewing each step of my code, I found out the problem. In one of my for loops I used int j=0; i<16; i++ instead of using j's. Stupid mistake but no one found it either so oh well. Corrected in the posted code.

Comment: Good on you.  A key scheduling problem.  I reformatted your code for readability (introducing white space) but didn't notice, I only spent around 3 hours (mostly looking up class references, I don't do Java).   Your comment "However, I found that the Key Permutation Tests were wrong. I assume that because the keys were wrong, the rest of the tests turned out wrong..." didn't make it clear whether the tests with zero keys passed or not. A guide on how to troubleshoot everything is book sized.